# Service worker doesn't see update

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, workbox

I have vue 3 application in which I have `registerServiceWorker.ts` file which is:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
        ready() {
            console.log('App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' + 'For more details, visit ');
        },
        registered() {
            console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
        },
        cached() {
            console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
        },
        updatefound() {
            console.log('New content is downloading.');
        },
        updated() {
            console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
        },
        offline() {
            console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
        },
        error(error) {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
        },
    });
}
```

This code is basically generated by CLI and I didnt change anything here. Basically it seems to work fine, it cache app and then serve it from cache even in offline mode. The issue is that when i release new version to the server I don't see `New content is available; please refresh.` although the index.html file changed completly. Is there some hidden way to tell service worker that new version of app was uploaded to the server?

Comment: The default Vue + pwa project works fine. Can't see the message on the production build? Are you sure you are not deleting console.log in your Webpack settings?